# RegEx Spacing in Function

Tags: java, regex, string, function, validation

I have to do a validation for a string with a function for example

```
Z = 3x + 5x
```

This string has to have space between them.

This is what I have on this moment:

```
s.matches(".*?\\S'+'\\S.*?") || s.matches(".*?\\S'='\\S.*?")
```

And doesn't work.

Comment: Try `s.matches("^\\pL\\s*=\\s*\\d+\\pL\\s*\\+\\s*\\d+\\pL$")`. `\pL` will match any letter and `\d` a digit.

Comment: I tried and doesn't wok. 
(s.matches(".*?\\S[+].*?" ) || s.matches(".*?[+]\\S.*?")); This works for + but for equal doens't

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to test your string with the `find` method (not the `matches` method) and this pattern:

```
[=+](?:(?<!\\s.)|(?!\\s))
```

if a match is found, the string isn't well formatted.

```
[=+]
(?:
    (?<!\\s.) # not preceded by a character ( + or = ) and a whitespace
  |           # OR
    (?!\\s)   # not followed by a whitespace
)
```

The advantage of using negated lookarounds here is that the limits of the string are taken in account too.